# Convert http response to json format in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, json.net, csom

I have a function that returns an http response I want to convert this return to json format to be able to retrieve and assign some values in a specific model.
I use net core 3.1

here is the model I want to make :

```
public class UserSharePointViewModel
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my function :

```
  public async Task<UserSharePointViewModel> GetUserProfilInfoFromSharePoint()
    {
        string accessToken = await GetAccessToken();

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration["SharePointConfiguration:WebSiteUrl"]);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|mellafi@naxxum.fr'");


            var finalData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var _dataResponse = JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalData));

            UserSharePointViewModel userResult = new UserSharePointViewModel()
            {
                AccountName = _dataResponse["AccountName"].ToString(),
                Email = _dataResponse["Email"].ToString(),
                DisplayName = _dataResponse["PersonalUrl"].ToString(),
                Picture = _dataResponse["PictureUrl"].ToString()
            };
            return userResult;
        }
    }
```

This function returns the following error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSharePointViewModel>(finalData);`?

Comment: Maybe the Propnames don‘t match, but you could Delfine Json-Attributes.

Comment: when i replace _dataResponse with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSharePointViewModel>(finalData); how can i access to a specific params like AccountName for example ?

Comment: Izzy is right, you should deserialize the entire thing, not use JToken. Also do a `Console.WriteLine(finalData)` to see the response and make sure it's a correct json.

Comment: JSON is a string. The response is already a string. At best, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalData)` will add an extra pair of quotes around the response, and `JToken.Parse` will return an entity whose value is just the original string. You don't convert a string to JSON , you convert *from* the JSON string to objects, using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: @DevRacker I have already debugged the response and it s ok but when I replace `var _dataResponse = JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalData));`  by  `var _dataResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSharePointViewModel>(finalData); ` how can i access to AccountName for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
private static readonly HttpClient httpcLient = new HttpClient();
public async Task<UserSharePointViewModel> GetUserProfilInfoFromSharePoint()
{
    string accessToken = await GetAccessToken();    
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration["SharePointConfiguration:WebSiteUrl"]);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("url");

    var finalData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var _dataResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSharePointViewModel>(finalData));

    UserSharePointViewModel userResult = new UserSharePointViewModel()
    {
        AccountName = _dataResponse.AccountName,
        Email = _dataResponse.Email,
        DisplayName = _dataResponse.PersonalUrl,
        Picture = _dataResponse.PictureUrl
    };
    return userResult;

}
```

By the way, you should NOT use HTTP like you are using it, HttpClient should be static and re-used, you should not use "using" with HttpClient.
Check this out for more info: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Thank You ! But my response from the http does not return an object of type UserSharePointViewModel.
What I want is to get from this response the value of some fields and assign them in the UserSharePointViewModel Dto

Comment: Could you please include an example of the response you get from the server?

Answer (score 0):

First de-serialize "finalData" to its corresponding object (UserSharePointResponse) then converting to UserSharePointViewModel would be a no-brainer. I also changed `Task<UserSharePointViewModel>` to `Task<JsonResult>` (not necessary though)

```
public async Task<JsonResult> /*Task<UserSharePointViewModel>*/ GetUserProfilInfoFromSharePoint()
{
    string accessToken = await GetAccessToken();

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration["SharePointConfiguration:WebSiteUrl"]);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|mellafi@naxxum.fr'");


        var finalData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //var _dataResponse = JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalData));
        var _dataResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSharePointResponse>(finalData);
    
        UserSharePointViewModel userResult = new UserSharePointViewModel()
        {
            AccountName = _dataResponse.AccountName,
            Email = _dataResponse.Email,
            DisplayName = _dataResponse.PersonalUrl,
            Picture = _dataResponse.PictureUrl
        };
        //return userResult;
        return Json(userResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

public class UserSharePointResponse
{
    public string PersonalUrl { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}
```